# vector 's actual color are being lost over another vector

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color

I have two vectors, the flower layer is on top of the box, transparency for both the layers are 100% opaque. I dunno why yellow petals of flowers are turning green when placed over the purple box.

[image]

Comment: Related: [How to make a color appear the same on different backgrounds?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/15494/23061)

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. What software are you using?

Comment: Check the blending mode of the petals, it looks like it's multiply. In vector drawing programs every shape can have its own blending mode, the layer can still have mode = normal.

Comment: It's Adobe Illustrator

Comment: Can you please check the blending mode as requested by @user287001.  It's difficult to answer this without access to the file. Only guesses are possible without more information. Thanks.

Comment: The blend mode of the petals could be set to *Multiply* or it could have *Attributes > Overprint Fill* turned on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Illustrator can give different attributes and blend modes to different paths inside groups.

The image below may show your situation.

[image]